# Running Commands on Startup

Tags: startup, yocto

I am following [this tutorial on using a mobile phone's accelerometer](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sparkfun-inventors-kit-for-edison-experiment-guide/experiment-11-phone-accelerometer).

In order for it to work properly you have to run three commands on startup every time...

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
killall bluetoothd
hciconfig hci0 up
```

Is there a way to do this with a script on startup instead of manually doing it every time?

Comment: Have tou tried the [cookbook instructions](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Cookbook:Appliance:Startup_Scripts)? (I don'tknow if they're up-to-date but they look plausible.)

Answer (score 1):

Most systems will automatically load `/etc/rc.local` on startup when present, so you just have to put your commands in there and that should do the trick.

You should make sure it is executable by root, but it probably already is.

Comment: I am really keen to try this out, I am currently putting all my system startup commands in my `~/.zshrc` file. as all the other places which are often recommended don't always work. do you know if `/etc/rc.local` is run late in boot, i.e. after all the graphical system is ready? for example, could I put `xset`  commands targeting X server in  there?

Comment: @the_velour_fog:  The `.zshrc` file will run once per session, not per boot.  This is not suitable for every command you need to run on startup.  I honestly don't know for your question on `xset` though, but it should take you 5-10 minutes to find out.

Comment: thanks, yes running the system startup commands every time I launch a new shell is overkill, but until now no other solution has worked. The other problem, is the system startup commands don't get run at all until I have launched a shell. Unfortunately I can't simply reboot to test, I've got too many daemons that won't restart, text editor sessions that might get lost and USB device plugged in which will lose state if I reboot

Comment: @the_velour_fog:  In my experience, when you're in such a situation is when you should put in efforts to properly automate your startup or otherwise it can quickly become a nightmare.

Comment: yes, well I will try your `/etc/rc.local` solution on next reboot, and hopefully that will get me one step closer to having a sane system!

Comment: @the_velour_fog `/etc/rc.local` is run as one of the last things, but still before the X server. If you want to run things when the X server starts, you have to modify a file that depends on how X starts — which display manager loads it.

Comment: @Gilles thanks. Also Im guessing that its not enough to setup the custom startup commands so that - chronologically -  they run after the xserver. but that the process that fork/execs the shell that runs those commands has descended from processes that initialised environment variables those custom startup commands would need?

Comment: @the_velour_fog Yes, if something requires X you need to run it with the right `DISPLAY` environment variable and possibly `XAUTHORITY`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126

Comment: I cant seem to find rc.local

Answer (score 0):

If your system uses systemd, you could write a oneshot service that executes the command once, at system boot.

First, create a file `/opt/scripts/configure-bluetooth.sh` and put your commands in:

```
#!/bin/bash
rfkill unblock bluetooth
killall bluetoothd
hciconfig hci0 up
```

And make the file executable: `chmod +x /opt/scripts/configure-bluetooth.sh`

The create a new service unit: `/etc/systemd/system/configure-bluetooth.service` That contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure bluetooth

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/scripts/configure-bluetooth.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should now run `systemctl daemon-reload` so that systemd detects the new service. To test it, run `systemctl start configure-bluetooth.service`.

Once you are sure that it works, you can enable it on boot with: `systemctl enable configure-bluetooth.service`

Comment: It works but every time I reboot the Edison I have to run the start command. I have tried multiple times to set this up but seems as though I doesn't automatically start.

Comment: I was probably wrong on the `WantedBy` target, see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251211/why-doesnt-my-systemd-user-unit-start-at-boot) link. Could you try to change `WantedBy=multi-user.target` to `WantedBy=default.target`? You might also need to use `systemctl --user enable configure.bluetooth` as described there.

Comment: I tried and after systemctl --user... I got "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused"