# Systemd user service not starting at boot even though lingering is enabled (user via NIS)

Tags: systemd, logind

Lingering has been enabled with

```
loginctl enable-linger
```

However, the user services do not start before logging in with the user. The services remain active when logging out again.

Is something extra needed to make it work when the user is not in the /etc/passwd file, but provided via NIS ?

The service is correctly added to the `default.target`, so this seems to be unrelated to [Why doesn't my systemd user unit start at boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251211/why-doesnt-my-systemd-user-unit-start-at-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding the user to the /etc/passwd file and not solely rely on NIS.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. `network-online.target` is not pulled in by default, so I don't think `systemd-logind` does anything with it; I guess logind doesn't know it needs to wait for your user details to become available...

Look up `nss-user-lookup.target`.  Maybe you're supposed to create a drop-in file so that `nss-user-lookup.target` gains `Wants=` and `After=` on `network-online.target`.

The comment in `nss-user-lookup.target` does not sound like your needs were anticipated.  "This exists mostly for implementations lacking socket/bus activation."

I believe SSSD implements caching for offline access.  So maybe when you use SSSD it could just work, without having to make everything wait for wifi.

It looks like non-SSSD solutions can also provide caching for offline access, but the default setting might not cache for long enough: https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/NSS#Offline_caching_of_NSS_with_nscd